# Any warnings related to react code for jest enzyme unit tests fails the tests instead of just displaying the warning

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have recently done jest enzyme configuration for my react project. The issue is any warning from react code causes my test cases to fail. Is there any way I can do the jest enzyme configuration so that my tests runs even when there is some warning? My code is fully functional and I want to ignore warnings for my tests and just want my test cases to run instead of failing immediately whenever any small warning comes.

Comment: What type of warnings? Could you show some examples..

Comment: react-prop-types warning which comes if I am using react v 15.5 and directly accessing prop-types from main react package.Missing key when I iterate through individual element of array and not provided key property to the element. Also, there are several other warnings which I just want jest to ignore instead of giving me the error.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: No, not solution yet. I guess I have to resolve all the warnings instead of ignoring them if I want my test cases to work

Answer (score 0):

To disable warning, you can use the `--silent` flag. So run your tests with `jest --silent`.